# react-native run-android doesn't build

Tags: react-native

I'm totally new in react-native and have an Android emulator running but it doesn't build react-native & shows this error...
what should i do?

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>     Could not download appcompat-v7.aar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0)
>     Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar'.
>     Connection reset
>     Could not download support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0)
>     Could not get resource
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 8m 56s
>   1 actionable task: 1 executed
>   error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
>   Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
>   set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
>   error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: It was because of internet problem . I live in Iran and unfortunately google's limited Iranian:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should update your node.js
Then run the installation's cammands and for Iranian it's better to use shecan.ir before running build run-android command instead of unworking vpn.
I did these steps and the problem solved.